# "Global" UIImagePicker Functionality for Multiple Classes

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on an app that (among other things) uses UIImagePicker to grab an image from the device once the user has selected the SourceType by tapping the appropriate button. Different sections of the app will need to use this functionality, as well as the variable holding the image information once selected. When I first started the project I had all of my code to do this in a single class named ViewController. I'm now working on moving the individual sections of the app into their own classes, but I'd like to be able to have them all use the UIImagePicker functionality from a central location.

Along with the necessary UIImagePickerController methods and protocols, I have a method that presents a view with buttons for each available SourceType. Each of these buttons then send a message to methods to show the appropriate picker (or the camera). Once an image is selected, it is applied to a variable for use by the different sections.

I wanted to get suggestions on the best way to approach this before I went to deep down the wrong rabbit hole.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a lot of your classes use this functionality, you can create a superclass (itself being a subclass of UIViewController).

This class will expose some method to launch the process you described, and some other to gather the information collected.

If you don't want to use inheritance, or you already to with another class, you can also create a separate class responsible for this process.
This class, which is not necessary a UIViewController, has to be instantiated and then called the same way the superclass described above.

Comment: Thanks, Geoffroy. I'm going to play with both suggestions, going with option 2 first.